# How to query if a vertex has multiple edges to other vertices with same label

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlinpython

I'm trying to figure which "filters" vertices have multiple edges to vertices with same label. For example, in this case "filter:2" has 2 edges going to vertices with label "projectType" same. This is also true for "filter:3" since it has 3 edges going out to vertices "projectType".

I tried to attempt the "loop" step but I always get an error from the console. I'm using AWS Neptune.

## Vertices

```
filter:1, filter 
filter:2, filter
filter:3, filter
projectType:1, projectType
projectType:2, projectType
projectType:3, projectType
projectType:4, projectType
city:1, city
city:2, city
city:3, city
```

## Edges

```
filter:1-projectType:1, services, filter:1, projectType:1
filter:2-projectType:1, services, filter:2, projectType:1
filter:2-projectType:2, services, filter:2, projectType:2
filter:3-projectType:2, services, filter:3, projectType:2
filter:3-projectType:3, services, filter:3, projectType:3
filter:3-projectType:4, services, filter:3, projectType:4
filter:1-city:2, services, filter:1, city:2
filter:2-city:1, services, filter:2, city:1
filter:3-city:1, services, filter:3, city:1
```

## Console code to create vertices and edges

```
g.addV('filter').property('id','filter:1').as('f1').addV('filter').property('id','filter:2').as('f2').addV('filter').property('id','filter:3').as('f3').addV('projectType').property('id','projectType:1').as('p1').addV('projectType').property('id','projectType:2').as('p2').addV('projectType').property('id','projectType:3').as('p3').addV('projectType').property('id','projectType:4').as('p4').addV('city').property('id','city:1').as('c1').addV('city').property('id','city:2').as('c2').addV('city').property('id','city:3').as('c3').addE('services').from('f1').to('p1').addE('services').from('f2').to('p1').addE('services').from('f2').to('p2').addE('services').from('f3').to('p2').addE('services').from('f3').to('p3').addE('services').from('f3').to('p4').addE('services').from('f1').to('c2').addE('services').from('f2').to('c1').addE('services').from('f3').to('c1')
```

```
g.V().hasLabel('filter').as('x').outE().inV().loop('x').{it.loops < 3}.path()
```

> {"requestId":"d63968ad-6c63-41f8-bfff-b31b09077a92","code":"MalformedQueryException","detailedMessage":"Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 68, error message : token recognition error at: 'it.'"}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear about what you want as a result given your attempt at solving your problem but If I take your question at face value, you seem to want to get a list of "filter" vertices that have multiple labels which would be "filter:2" and "filter:3". If that is the case, then:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('filter').
......1>   filter(out().
......2>          groupCount().by(label).
......3>          unfold().
......4>          select(values).
......5>          is(gt(1))).
......6>   values('id')
==>filter:2
==>filter:3
```

The `filter()` step traverses on outgoing edges and takes count of all the labels on the adjacent vertices. Then on line 3 it unfolds that resulting `Map` of labels and counts and extracts just the counts (i.e. `select(values)` extracts the value of the key/value pair in the `Map` entry which is the count) and then filters those counts with `is(gt(1))` signifying that the current vertex has at least one situation where there are adjacent vertices with more than one label